# Extension of Contented Functions to Absolutely Integrable Functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm working through Lynn H. Loomis and Shlomo Sternberg's book Advanced Calculus (revised edition) http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf. I'm on chapter 8, section 13: ABSOLUTELY INTEGRABLE FUNCTIONS. By this point in the book, the authors are going much faster and not proving all the fine details, and I'm struggling to prove something they glossed over. They extended the concept of contented function to absolutely integrable functions (don't be thrown by the name "absolutely integrable" here; it's not the same concept you see in wikipedia), and they claimed that this extension satisfies F1 - F3 in section 9 of the same chapter. In particular, I'm stuck trying to prove that the sum of any absolutely integrable functions is absolutely integrable (properties i and ii the first page of section 13).

I know this is very specific, and I'm not sure if it's too specific for this forum. I know that I didn't write out all the definitions in this post; it's fairly involved and one would have to refer to the book to understand/review the notion of contented functions (defined in earlier sections of chapter 8). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is a contented function?

Comment: According to the book, a function $f: ℝ^n \to ℝ$ is called a contented function if for all $\delta$, there exists paved functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ such that $g1 \le f \le g2$ and $\int g2 - g1 < \delta $. A paved function $g$ has the form $\Sigma c_i e_{A_i} $ where $e_{A_i} = 1$ on $A_i$, where $A_i$ are disjoint rectangles in $ℝ^n$ (that is, $A_i = \{(x_1,..,x_n) | a_i \le x_i \lt b_i\}$),  and $0$ otherwise, for finite $i$. The integral of a paved function is $\int g = \Sigma c_i \mu(A_i)$, where $\mu(A_i)$ is the volume of a rectangle; $\mu(A_i) = \Pi_i(b_i - a_i) $.